# Using Syphon Send Frames for VDMX

Tags: processing

I am having trouble merging my processing sketch
 with VDMX.

When I run the example code, it works fine:

```
//Syphon Library - EXAMPLE Send Frames

import codeanticode.syphon.*;

PGraphics canvas;
SyphonServer server;

void setup() {
  size(400,400, P3D);
  canvas = createGraphics(400, 400, P3D);

  // Create syhpon server to send frames out.
  server = new SyphonServer(this, "Processing Syphon");
}

void draw() {
  canvas.beginDraw();
  canvas.background(127);
  canvas.lights();
  canvas.translate(width/2, height/2);
  canvas.rotateX(frameCount * 0.01);
  canvas.rotateY(frameCount * 0.01);  
  canvas.box(150);
  canvas.endDraw();
  image(canvas, 0, 0);
  server.sendImage(canvas);
}
```

But when I try to merge it with my current code, I get problems. My current sketch consists on Color Tracking from live webcam feed. It is not supposed to "show" what the webcam is recording, but it is supposed to show the interaction.

```
//Final Project
//Krisia Ayala _ Prof.David Rios
//This sketch is supposed to merge all the codes in one.

import codeanticode.syphon.*;
import processing.video.*;

//Send Sketch to Syphon

Capture video;
long rs;
int num = 57, frames=10;
float theta;
PGraphics canvas;
SyphonServer server;

void setup() {
  size(640, 480);
  rs = (long) random(34);
  video = new Capture(this, width, height, 15);
  video.start();
  noStroke();
  smooth();
  frameRate(15); //ellipses
  smooth();
  background(255);
  server = new SyphonServer(this, "Processing Syphon");
  String [] animas = {
  };
}

void draw() {
  if (video.available()) {
    video.read();
    server.sendImage(canvas);
    //image(video, 0, 0, width, height);
    //color tracking
    int colorX = 0; // X-coordinate of the closest in color video pixel
    int colorY = 0; // Y-coordinate of the closest in color video pixel
    float closestColor = 500; //we set this to be abritrarily large, once program runs, the first pixel it scans will be set to this value
    // Search for the closest in color pixel: For each row of pixels in the video image and
    // for each pixel in the yth row, compute each pixel's index in the video

    video.loadPixels();
    int index = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < video.height; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < video.width; x++) {
        // Get the color stored in the pixel
        color pixelValue = video.pixels[index];
        // Determine the color of the pixel
        float colorProximity = abs(red(pixelValue)-27)+abs(green(pixelValue)-162)+abs(blue(pixelValue)-181);
        if (colorProximity < closestColor) {
          closestColor = colorProximity;
          closestColor=closestColor-10; //thoguht behind this is that it once it "locks" on to an object of color, it wont let go unless something a good bit better (closer in color) comes along
          colorY = y;
          colorX = x;
        }
        index++;
      }
    }  

    //tracking
    smooth();
   // rect(0, 0, width+2, height+2);
   // ellipse(0, 0, width-4, height-4);
    fill(255);
    randomSeed(rs);
    for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
      float x = random(790);
      float y2=20;
      float y = random(height/2-y2, height/2+y2);
      float offSet = map(x, 0, width, 0, TWO_PI);
      float d=70;
      float varY = map(sin(theta+offSet), -1, 1, -d, d);
      float varX = map(sin(theta+offSet*3), -1, 1, -d*2, d*2);
      float sz = 1;
      ellipse(colorX, colorY, 1, 2);
    }
//    theta+= TWO_PI/frames+120/2 ; 
//    if (frameCount>120 && frameCount<frames+120) saveFrame("image-###.gif");


   // noStroke();
   // fill(0, 0, 0, 128);
    //ellipse(colorX, colorY, 60, 40);

   // ellipse(colorX, colorY, 10, 10);
   // stroke(120);
    //process - white ellipse followed by a line: https://gyazo.com/d7d2c11c856dfdfddccd5816207ef859


     fill(0, 50);
  rect(0, 0, width+2, height+2);
  //ellipse(0, 0, width-4, height-4);
  fill(34, 255);
  randomSeed(rs);
  for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
    float x = random(7809);
    float y2=20;
    float y = random(height/2-y2, height/2+y2);
    float offSet = map(x, 0, width, 0, TWO_PI*3);
    float d=90;
    float varY = map(sin(theta+offSet), -1, 1, -d, d);
    float varX = map(sin(theta+offSet*2), -1, 1, -d*2, d*2);
    float sz = 1;
   ellipse(colorX+varX, colorY+varY, sz, sz);
   ellipse(colorX+varX+2, colorY+varY, TWO_PI, sz);
  }
  //theta+= TWO_PI/frames;

  }
  theta+= TWO_PI/frames;
    theta+= TWO_PI+2/frames;
}
```

The problem I think I have is I don't know the term I should change "canvas" for.... Or if that's even the problem....
Any help will be great, thank you!
-K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code in it's current form:

1. The canvas variable is never initialised, nor used [to draw into](https://processing.org/reference/createGraphics_.html).
2. You're calling `server.sendImage(canvas);` straight after reading a video frame

This line: `server.sendImage(canvas);` should be called at the end of the video processing and drawing you do, not straight after you grabbed a new frame.

You could cheat and use Processing's [get()](https://processing.org/reference/get_.html) function to fetch a 'screenshot' of the current frame after you've drawn everything, and send that to Syphon.

Something like this:

```
//Final Project
//Krisia Ayala _ Prof.David Rios
//This sketch is supposed to merge all the codes in one.

import codeanticode.syphon.*;
import processing.video.*;

//Send Sketch to Syphon

Capture video;
long rs;
int num = 57, frames=10;
float theta;
PGraphics canvas;
SyphonServer server;

void setup() {
  size(640, 480, P2D);
  rs = (long) random(34);
  video = new Capture(this, width, height, 15);
  video.start();
  noStroke();
  smooth();
  frameRate(15); //ellipses
  smooth();
  background(255);
  server = new SyphonServer(this, "Processing Syphon");
  String [] animas = {
  };
}

void draw() {
  //color tracking
  int colorX = 0; // X-coordinate of the closest in color video pixel
  int colorY = 0; // Y-coordinate of the closest in color video pixel
  float closestColor = 500; //we set this to be abritrarily large, once program runs, the first pixel it scans will be set to this value
  // Search for the closest in color pixel: For each row of pixels in the video image and
  // for each pixel in the yth row, compute each pixel's index in the video
  video.loadPixels();
  int index = 0;
  for (int y = 0; y < video.height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < video.width; x++) {
      // Get the color stored in the pixel
      color pixelValue = video.pixels[index];
      // Determine the color of the pixel
      float colorProximity = abs(red(pixelValue)-27)+abs(green(pixelValue)-162)+abs(blue(pixelValue)-181);
      if (colorProximity < closestColor) {
        closestColor = colorProximity;
        closestColor=closestColor-10; //thoguht behind this is that it once it "locks" on to an object of color, it wont let go unless something a good bit better (closer in color) comes along
        colorY = y;
        colorX = x;
      }
      index++;
    }
  }  

  //tracking
  smooth();
  // rect(0, 0, width+2, height+2);
  // ellipse(0, 0, width-4, height-4);
  fill(255);
  randomSeed(rs);
  for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
    float x = random(790);
    float y2=20;
    float y = random(height/2-y2, height/2+y2);
    float offSet = map(x, 0, width, 0, TWO_PI);
    float d=70;
    float varY = map(sin(theta+offSet), -1, 1, -d, d);
    float varX = map(sin(theta+offSet*3), -1, 1, -d*2, d*2);
    float sz = 1;
    ellipse(colorX, colorY, 1, 2);
  }

  fill(0, 50);
  rect(0, 0, width+2, height+2);
  fill(34, 255);
  randomSeed(rs);
  for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
    float x = random(7809);
    float y2=20;
    float y = random(height/2-y2, height/2+y2);
    float offSet = map(x, 0, width, 0, TWO_PI*3);
    float d=90;
    float varY = map(sin(theta+offSet), -1, 1, -d, d);
    float varX = map(sin(theta+offSet*2), -1, 1, -d*2, d*2);
    float sz = 1;
    ellipse(colorX+varX, colorY+varY, sz, sz);
    ellipse(colorX+varX+2, colorY+varY, TWO_PI, sz);
  }

  theta+= TWO_PI/frames;
  theta+= TWO_PI+2/frames;

  //send a screenshot from Processing to Syhpn
  server.sendImage(get());
}
void captureEvent(Capture c) {
  c.read();
}
```

If you want to use the `canvas` PGraphics instance, you can try something like this:

```
//Final Project
//Krisia Ayala _ Prof.David Rios
//This sketch is supposed to merge all the codes in one.

import codeanticode.syphon.*;
import processing.video.*;

//Send Sketch to Syphon

Capture video;
long rs;
int num = 57, frames=10;
float theta;
PGraphics canvas;
SyphonServer server;

void setup() {
  size(640, 480, P2D);
  rs = (long) random(34);
  video = new Capture(this, width, height, 15);
  video.start();
  noStroke();
  smooth();
  frameRate(15); //ellipses
  smooth();
  background(255);
  server = new SyphonServer(this, "Processing Syphon");
  String [] animas = {
  };
  //initialize the canvas
  canvas = createGraphics(width,height,P2D);
}

void draw() {
  //color tracking
  int colorX = 0; // X-coordinate of the closest in color video pixel
  int colorY = 0; // Y-coordinate of the closest in color video pixel
  float closestColor = 500; //we set this to be abritrarily large, once program runs, the first pixel it scans will be set to this value
  // Search for the closest in color pixel: For each row of pixels in the video image and
  // for each pixel in the yth row, compute each pixel's index in the video
  video.loadPixels();
  int index = 0;
  for (int y = 0; y < video.height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < video.width; x++) {
      // Get the color stored in the pixel
      color pixelValue = video.pixels[index];
      // Determine the color of the pixel
      float colorProximity = abs(red(pixelValue)-27)+abs(green(pixelValue)-162)+abs(blue(pixelValue)-181);
      if (colorProximity < closestColor) {
        closestColor = colorProximity;
        closestColor=closestColor-10; //thoguht behind this is that it once it "locks" on to an object of color, it wont let go unless something a good bit better (closer in color) comes along
        colorY = y;
        colorX = x;
      }
      index++;
    }
  }  

  //tracking
  canvas.beginDraw();
  canvas.smooth();
  // rect(0, 0, width+2, height+2);
  // ellipse(0, 0, width-4, height-4);
  canvas.fill(255);
  randomSeed(rs);
  for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
    float x = random(790);
    float y2=20;
    float y = random(height/2-y2, height/2+y2);
    float offSet = map(x, 0, width, 0, TWO_PI);
    float d=70;
    float varY = map(sin(theta+offSet), -1, 1, -d, d);
    float varX = map(sin(theta+offSet*3), -1, 1, -d*2, d*2);
    float sz = 1;
    canvas.ellipse(colorX, colorY, 1, 2);
  }

  canvas.fill(0, 50);
  canvas.rect(0, 0, width+2, height+2);
  canvas.fill(34, 255);
  randomSeed(rs);
  for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
    float x = random(7809);
    float y2=20;
    float y = random(height/2-y2, height/2+y2);
    float offSet = map(x, 0, width, 0, TWO_PI*3);
    float d=90;
    float varY = map(sin(theta+offSet), -1, 1, -d, d);
    float varX = map(sin(theta+offSet*2), -1, 1, -d*2, d*2);
    float sz = 1;
    canvas.ellipse(colorX+varX, colorY+varY, sz, sz);
    canvas.ellipse(colorX+varX+2, colorY+varY, TWO_PI, sz);
  }
  canvas.endDraw();

  theta+= TWO_PI/frames;
  theta+= TWO_PI+2/frames;

  //render canvas in processing
  image(canvas,0,0);
  //send canvas to Syphon
  server.sendImage(canvas);
}
void captureEvent(Capture c) {
  c.read();
}
```

This be useful in terms of sending frames using Syphon.
You should double check that your tracking code is working as expected.
It's unclear what you're trying to achieve...drawing some ellipses around a colour tracked area ?

Comment: Yes, I want to draw some ellipses around the color tracked area. And I want to use VDMX to delete the background color... So that's why I don't want to show the actual video feed.  
Thank you George!

Comment: You should be able to draw ellipses around the color tracked area without using VDMX: analyse pixels from the most recent Capture frame, but simply don't render it, just render the ellipses instead.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I just figured that out, when I tried to map to a surface.

Comment: Thank you for the help!! :)

Comment: No problem and goodluck with the rest of it. Share a link when it's done, sounds interesting :)

Comment: Hi George, do you think you can help me add a flocking behavior to this code? I would like the ellipses to behave with Flocking Behaviors: Alignment, Cohesion, and Separation, but I don't know where to put those variables

Comment: I'd post that as a separate question (this way this topic will be clear and you'll be likely to get answers from others as well). I recommend starting to play with the existing examples(**Examples > Topics > Simulate > Flocking**) and [Nature of Code](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-6-autonomous-agents/). How familiar are you with OOP basics (classes/objects) ?

Comment: I am not at all familiar, I've been referred to the text before, but I really don't understand it. I am new to coding and very fond of birds and I would like to learn as much as I can. How would you format a new question to describe what I am after?

Comment: Ideally you would build a knowledge base that will allow you to understand flocking. On the syntax side, simply understand objects and how to use it's properties(an objects' variables) and methods(an objects' functions) should suffice. The slightly trickier part is the bit of math behind it (a bit of linear algebra: vectors in particular). If at the moment you can't afford the time to acquire this base, you should be able to use start playing with the existing code. In a way you're asking how can you use flocking without understanding OOP and vector maths, but I'm not sure how well received...

Comment: ...the question will be since people will expect you to put in effort and understand it. The Nature of Code site does a very good job at explaining the flocking algorithm, but if that presentation format isn't helpful, try [Daniel Shiffman's video tutorial series on flocking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JIz2L4tn5kM&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6YHt0dtyf4uiw8tKOxQLvlW). The code is already written for you, but at least getting a hang of how it works will allow you to use it better....At least start with the samples (NOC_06_08_SeparationAndSeek sounds like what you need)....

Comment: ...Play with it first, then make a copy and tweak to get closer to your goal. If it works: perfect! If it doesn't show what you've tried and ask how to resolve the issue